# Скажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, извините за код учу пайтон 1 день

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
one = float(input("первое число:  ")

row = float(input("равно:  ")

what = input("действие:  ")
if what == "+"
    x = one - row
    print(one + what + x + "=" + row)
elif what == "-"
    x = one + row
    print(one + what + x + "=" + row)
elif what == "/"
    x = one / row
    print(one + what + x + "=" + row)
elif what == "*"
    x = row / one
    print(one + what + x + "=" + row)
```

Comment: Добавлю к выше сказанному. Не спешите! Старайтесь подробно выучить каждую тему, потому что так вам будет ГОРАЗДО проще, и ещё вы сможете решить больше задач чем в спешку

Answer (score 6):

1. В первых двух строчках не хватает скобок
2. Нельзя складывать переменные типов **float** и **string** друг с другом
3. Нет двоеточий после блоков **if** и **elif**
4. Путаница с действиями и переменными

**Исправленный код:**

```
one = float(input("первое число:  "))
row = float(input("второе число:  "))
what = input("действие:  ")

if what == "+":
    x = one + row
    print(one, what, row, "=", x)

elif what == "-":
    x = one - row
    print(one, what, row, "=", x)

elif what == "/":
    x = one / row
    print(one, what, row, "=", x)

elif what == "*":
    x = row * one
    print(one, what, row, "=", x)
```

Comment: Так там и действия все перепутаны, тогда и их исправьте. А то код всё-равно неправильно работает.